# AWS Lambda - Can't get Cognito user data in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get Cognito user data in a lambda function. I am trying to pass it to lambda using `body mapping template` as

```
{
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
}
```

But, in the lambda function, the data is coming empty as

```
'cognito-authentication-provider': '',
'cognito-authentication-type': '',
'cognito-identity-id': '',
'cognito-identity-pool-id': ''
```

Please help me solve this.

Thanks...

**EDIT:**
Added Cognito authentication `dev-dummy-auth` as
[image]

Comment: Did you verify $context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider actually contains what you want it to contain?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge Actually, I want to know the cognito user pool group in which the user is present.

Comment: @KMo Yes. I am using Cognito User Pool Authorizers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on Dilip Kola's answer. It appears that the context variables you are trying to access do not exist for the authorization method you are using.

The only way I can see to get the token information to the underlying Lambda service is to pass the whole token down and open it in the Lambda with an appropriate library for the language you are using.

You can pass the token by adding a line to your body mapping template.

```
{"Authorization" : "$input.params().header.get('Authorization')"}
```

A Cognito ID token is in the form of a JWT (JSON Web Token). The `ISS` claim is in the format `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}`.

**Update - To include information about User Groups**

The Cognito Identity token does not contain the User Groups of the user who was issued the token.

To restrict API access to individuals in certain User Groups, you will have to change your authentication method to AWS_IAM Authorizer using Cognito Federated Identities.

An alternative would be to use a custom attribute such as role in Cognito marking certain users as Admin, User, etc (as these can be passed in the id token) then evaluating that custom attribute. If you were going to go down this route, I would move to a Custom Lambda Authorizer method of authentication. This way you can check the custom attributes at the same time you validate the token, so requests don't ever reach the backend if the user does not have the correct access rights.

Comment: @K Mo Thanks. Now I am able to get the data through the token. I want to ask another question that, I want to give access to API endpoints from application to few people like admin. As, in user pools, if the user belongs to the admin group, then he can access the API endpoint. What is the way to do that? Help me, please.

Comment: @SaiUnique I've updated my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: @K Mo Thanks. Can you please provide me resource(video or docs) to follow and implement the same. I will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference
You are referring to the context variables for API request using cognito identity pool credentials, when you use cognito user pool authorizer these won’t be available.

Comment: I have created group in `cognito user pool authorizer`. And I want to get that group data for particular person.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable `Use Lambda Proxy inegration` in `Integration Request`, ewverything will show up in `event['requestContext']['authorizer']['claims']`